# How to MYSQL Increment Number restart in this query

Tags: mysql

i want my query display with column a sequence number which start to 1 again when there is new name .

Can anyone help me the MYSQL Query?

this is my vtiger query

```
select 
date_format(vtiger_crmentity.createdtime,'%d-%m-%Y') as Tanggal_Transaksi,
vendorname as Machine_Type,
vtiger_leaddetails.lastname as "Tipe Kartu",
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid as "Member",
vtiger_contactdetails.firstname as "Nama Depan",
vtiger_contactdetails.lastname as "Nama Belakang",
vtiger_servicecontractscf.cf_1085 as "Nama Bank",
campaignname as "No. Kartu",
cf_1095 as Total_Gesek,
" " as Saldo,
vtiger_accounting_payments.amount as Gsk,
" " as Kurang_Gesek,
rolename as Cabang
FROM
vtiger_accounting_payments, vtiger_accounting, vtiger_servicecontracts,       
vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_sqlreports,  
vtiger_sqlreportscf,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, vtiger_users, vtiger_vendor, vtiger_vendorcf, vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails,  vtiger_campaign
WHERE vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155
and vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid
and vtiger_leaddetails.leadid=cf_1091
and vtiger_vendor.vendorid=vtiger_vendorcf.vendorid
and vtiger_vendorcf.cf_1077=vtiger_accounting_payments.machinename
and vtiger_accounting.accountingid=vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction
and vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid
and vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0
and vtiger_sqlreports.sqlreportsid=216
and vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id
and vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid
and vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid
and rolename=cf_1205
and vtiger_sqlreports.sqlreportsid=vtiger_sqlreportscf.sqlreportsid  
and vtiger_sqlreports.sqlreportsid=216
and date_format(vtiger_crmentity.createdtime,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_format(cf_1157,'%Y-%m-%d') and date_format(vtiger_crmentity.createdtime,'%Y-%m-%d') <=date_format(cf_1159,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Not enough information. Do you want to retrieve records or want to add in database?

Comment: Pls provide the table definition.

Comment: It all the Nos are generated automatically, that will be strange. If explicitly specified, it is possible.

Comment: hello PHPExpert. i want to retrieve this

Comment: hello All pls see my edited Question. thx

Comment: I think, you should better try to work it out using server side script than MYSQL itself, it is complicated to do it with MYSQL alone.

Comment: hi shashikant_ pls think that my condition cannot use pHP server script :)

Comment: There really is no good reason for storing this in a database, however this can be achieved by using a MyISAM engine and defining your primary key as (name,id), where id is an autoincrementing integer. The manus covers this in more detail.

Comment: hi Dylan Su. can u type in here what syntax in SQL Server to accomplish this? That you have just deleted

Comment: i want to keep it as reference

Answer (score 1):

Use a user variable for the counter, and reset it to 1 whenever the name changes.

```
SELECT @no := IF(name = @prevName, @no + 1, 1) AS no,
       @prevName := name AS name, hobby
FROM (SELECT name, hobby
      FROM kids AS k
      JOIN kidshobby AS kh ON k.NameID = kh.NameID
      JOIN hobby AS h ON hk.HobbyID = h.HobbyID
      ORDER BY name, hobby) AS nh
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @no = 0, @prevName = '') AS vars
```

Comment: Helo Barmar... would you mind change your solution with Edited question above with title ".. for Barmar" thats my real MYSQL. i have applied your solution to my syntax but still error. what i want to reset when field vtiger_contactdetails.contactid (Member) changes

Comment: because i simulate the Hobby query and it display "1" for all records

Answer (score 0):

You can use a built in function ROW_NUMBER(). More details here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

And your query would be something like this.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS No, Name, Hobby FROM TableName;
```

Comment: Yeah, I realised it after I wrote the answer. My bad.

Comment: can u delete this Dylan?